# Low Search - not respecting hidden field/param

Tags: low-search

In my search form I have this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="programs_courses_show_in_results" value="Yes">
```

And in the results I have this:

```
{exp:low_search:results 
  channel="programs_courses"
  entry_id="not 110"
  limit="100"
  query="{segment_4}"}

  {if count == 1}{total_results}{/if}

  {if count ==  1}<ol>{/if}

      <li><a href="#">{title}</a> <small>Count: {count} | Show: {programs_courses_show_in_results}</small></li>

  {if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}

  {if no_results}No search results{/if}

{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Technically, I also have some category parameters in the search form, but if I leave those alone and only hit the search button, the results show everything in the channel, not just the ones with the `programs_courses_show_in_results` field set to "Yes".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [how parameters work](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#params), you need to prefix the var with `low_search_`.

**Edited to elaborate:**

The prefix is for outputting the parameter value as a variable. So, as shown in the docs, this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="param_name" value="param_value">
```

...results in the variable `{low_search_param_name}`. To translate that to your setup, having this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="programs_courses_show_in_results" value="Yes">
```

...would mean `{low_search_programs_courses_show_in_results}` would output `Yes`.

However, you don't want just to output `Yes`. As I understand it now, `programs_courses_show_in_results` is actually a custom field that can contain the value `Yes`, so you want to filter search results and only display entries where that fields equals `Yes`, like you can with the native `exp:channel:entries` tag using the parameter `search:programs_courses_show_in_results="Yes"`.

To achieve this in Low Search, use the [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search), so you can either use that exact parameter on the `exp:low_search:results` tag, or use a (hidden) field in the Form tag, thusly:

```
<input type="hidden" name="search:programs_courses_show_in_results" value="Yes">
```

...which means you can output `Yes` using `{low_search_search:programs_courses_show_in_results}`

Comment: Yeah, I've read through the docs thoroughly and adding the prefix didn't change anything. I changed the hidden input to `<input type="hidden" name="low_search_programs_courses_show_in_results" value="Yes">` and also tried `<input type="hidden" name="{low_search_programs_courses_show_in_results}" value="Yes">` (which I know is wrong). The results page still shows all the entries in that channel, rather than just the ones with that field set to Yes. (It's a dropdown select field, if that matters).

Comment: Perhaps my edited post will clarify things.

Comment: Ah, ok. That does work. Was about to switch to using a Status, but this works better. Thanks.